# Acess /system of android

Tags: permissions, android, file-management

I have a Huwaei SCC U21 with Android 5.0 and EMUI 3.0. I wanted to edit the host file in /system/etc using my laptop (Windows 10), but I couldn't find the system files of Android. Take a look at this [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mT4o.png) for further details. You can see that there is no /system.

Properties:

-temporarily rooted

I have tried:

1. Android Commander
2. Device driver update

Comment: Did you check show hidden files, folders and drives in the folder options? May want to uncheck hide protected operating system files as well.

Comment: I had tried that already and later I used adb's following command:                                           adb shell ls -R /
Here I can see all files.

Answer (score 0):

from the screenshot you provided ,it look likes you have connected your phone via Mtp mode.
there is another mode called usb storage ,which acts like pluging usb drive to pc .
but in both mode what you see is 
/mnt/sdcard/   or
/mnt/emmc/
folders mounted as separate partitions.

but  your hosts file is located at

/system/etc/hosts.

just look at this

[image: mnt and system both are subdirectory under root]

so you cant see it directly in windows explorer .
if your phone is rooted and you have working `adb` on windows.
then
you can try

```
adb pull /system/etc/hosts D:\hosts.txt
```

make a backup copy of it..

and then edit hosts.txt file.

and

```
adb push  D:\hosts.txt /system/etc/hosts
```

short way would be this

install any file explorer which have ability to see root and  edit text files(My favourite is xplore from lcg).

go directly to /system /etc 
make copy of hosts file somewhere else.

open hosts file as text in edit mode

edit.

save.

done...
done...